# How to add multiple icons to .app file using AppBundler

Tags: java, ant

I'm using appbundler to build .app file from my java project. This's main script in build file:

```
<taskdef name="bundleapp" classname="com.oracle.appbundler.AppBundlerTask"
    classpath="appbundler-1.0.jar" />

<target name="bundle-myApp">
    <bundleapp outputdirectory="${dist.dir}" name="MyApp"
        displayname="MyApp" identifier="com.myapp.Main"
        mainclassname="com.myapp.Main" shortversion="1.0" icon="../icon.icns">
        <runtime dir="${env.JAVA_HOME}" />
        <classpath file="${dist.dir}/${jar.file}" />
        <option value="-Xdock:icon=../Resources/icon.icns"></option>
    </bundleapp>
</target>
```

But when I submit my app, I got this error: The application bundler does not contain an icon in ICNS format, containing both a 512x512 and a 512x512@2x image. For further assistance, see the Apple Human Interface Guidelines. 
So, my questions are how to add multiple icons using appbundler script (not add manually). Thanks you!